# Import Excel into SQL - Datetime conversion fail

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I'm trying to import a excel into my SQL Database but I'm getting this error:

> Messages
>   Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

The database expects this data:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime hechosf_periodo { get; set; }
```

A sample of how this data is stored:

[image]

And this is how the data is entered into the Excel:

[image]

SQL identifies the excel column as datetime and will try to convert it to datetime2.

What can I do in order to pass this error?

[image]

**Update:**

After reviewing the Post-execute report

[image]

I've seen that is trying to read more rows that are **empty**. I've trying deleting the content of every cell in the sheet but this still persists.

Comment: Use the "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss" or "YYYMMDD" format.

Comment: @JasonA.Long Hello. Why is that? Why we should use a format with year upfront? As I can see the data already in the database it is using dd/mm/yyyy format. Using another format won't mess it up?

Comment: Those are the two universal, ansi standard, date / time standard formats. The 1st is for datetime and the second is date w/o time. They are also the two formats that will work no matter what default collation you're using.

Comment: I've changed it as recommended. (will update question with pictures) but still got the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 0):

You should to use **Derived Column Transformation** between the Source and Destination elements in your flow, which [descripted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-2017).

Are you see an @[System::StartTime] variable? You should to add your column (from the left pane) instead of this variable, and to choose the appropriate type in casting function from **Type Casts** folder (see the rigth pane). See mapping between the SSIS and the SQL types [at this page](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2014/05/27/sql-server-ssis-and-biml-data-types/). 
It will be *DT_DBTIMESTAMP* of *DT_DBTIMESTAMP2*, and an expression will looks like a `[DT_DBTIMESTAMP]old_column_name`. In **Derived Column** you need to left option "add new...", then you need to name this new column and use this new in the **Destination** element instead of excel "time" column.

 [image]